# Can't Connect to IIS 7.5 from another 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, remote-access, comexception

I am trying to execute this command from a web application on sourceServer:

var mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote(destServer)

but I receive this error:

UnAuthorized access wth a detail error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine  failed due to the following error: 80070005"

I have full administrative rights on both servers.

I can issue that command from a console application no problem, but when I try it from the web application, I get the error!

I have tried enabling the remote management checkbox and started teh remote access auto connection manager and also tried updating the load user profile on the applicaiton pool from false to true.

I have searched so much to the point that all of my links are pink in color!

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191634/remote-connection-to-iis7-using-servermanager-openremote/ for possible resolution

Comment: thanks for posting it. My firewall at both servers is off, so it is not related to firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to ditch the use of ServerManager.OpenRemote() and use the DirectoryEntry way:
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://server/W3SVC", username, password)
it is much simpler and straightforward.

Comment: The only problem is that using DirectoryEntry through the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll. Additional information: Unknown error (0x80005000)